# How do I use a dll file in an MVC C# project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

Im workning on an MVC web application. I have all the functions that I need to query the database. These functions are embedded in a Dll file that can be added to references as a reference. This dll file contains all the functions to (insert, delete, retrieve data from database). Is there any idea about how to use the function in the Dll file in my MVC project to handle with the database?

Answer (score 6):

Add the `using Namespace;` in any of your classes in the MVC Project where `Namespace` is the namespace of your class in the dll and try the following:

```
var myClass = new MyClassInThatDll(); 
myClass.DoIt();
```